# Supervisor failing to run celery beat

Tags: python-3.x, celery, supervisord

I am trying to run the `celery beat` on my server, but I am receiving the following error:

```
[2016-06-10 11:32:49,985: WARNING/MainProcess] self._index[key] = self._setval(pos, val)
[2016-06-10 11:32:49,985: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dbm/dumb.py", line 166, in _setval
[2016-06-10 11:32:49,985: WARNING/MainProcess] with _io.open(self._datfile, 'rb+') as f:
[2016-06-10 11:32:49,985: WARNING/MainProcess] PermissionError
[2016-06-10 11:32:49,986: WARNING/MainProcess] :
[2016-06-10 11:32:49,986: WARNING/MainProcess] [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'celerybeat-schedule.dat'
No local settings found
celery beat v3.1.23 (Cipater) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://localhost:6379/0
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> now (0s)

[2016-06-10 11:35:28,814: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting..
```

I do not know why the permission is denied for `celerybeat-schedule.dat`, since I am setting the user and permission in my config file:

```
[program:project_celery_beat]
command=/home/project/_env/bin/celery beat -A project --loglevel=INFO --pidfile=/tmp/celerybeat-myapp.pid
directory=/home/project/project/app/
user=project
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/project/celery_beat.log
stderr_logfile=/home/project/celery_beat.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopsignal=QUIT
environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="project.settings.sandbox":
```

How do I solve this permission problem?

Comment: This might be silly, but does the user `project`has read permissions on the `celerybeat-schedule.dat` file?

Comment: Do not know... i tried to change the file to a folder that the user has permission, but got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today. I solved it by putting:

`user = <An actual non-root user>`

it's strange because for celery you can actually put in a non-existent user and it works fine.